# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reposition') at MatSelect.eval [as _scrollStrategyFactory]

Tags: angular, angular-material, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Running unit test for component but keep getting error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reposition') at
> MatSelect.eval [as _scrollStrategyFactory]

I have imported `MatSelectModule` and `MatOptionModule` in imports of spec file.
At the same time I keep getting error:

> [object ErrorEvent] thrown

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was able to find the problem:

I had a wrong module imported:

```js
import { Overlay } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
```

After deleting it from the imports, the error was gone.

How I found this solution?
I opened the url of karma localhost:9876 parallel in Firefox. Surprisingly it showed me an complete different error message, but with more infos:

`TypeError: overlay.ScrollStrategies is undefined`

parallel, the chrome showed not such a detailed error message.

So I rethought my debugging strategy and started to scan my code for "overlay". So I found this useless import and it fixed my error.